# How to append a text to a button in bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

Does anybody know how to append or prepend a text with button without any input field like code below
Or is it even possible to do that?

```
<b-form-group class="mt-3">
    <b-input-group :prepend="color" v-b-modal.modal-1>
      <b-button class="custome-color" :style="{ background: this.color }" >
        <b-badge pill variant="light">
          {{ this.color }}
        </b-badge>
      </b-button>
    </b-input-group>
  </b-form-group>
```

Comment: What does "prepend" mean here? Button text is usually just on the button. How is this different? Maybe a snippet of plain HTML showing your desired outcome would help.

Comment: Prepend and append are used in bootstrap vue they fit to the input so they look grouped together

Comment: Yep. What does that mean with a _button_? Part of a button that's not clickable? Why would you want that?

Comment: Actually it the label of it somehow and they just stick together to look cleaner and more in shape i just wanted a button and that sticky label together with width 100% button that won't go to next row

Comment: _Buttons don't have labels_. You're proposing a very confusing UI.